# al referirme a una llave de matriz aparece indefinida

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

tengo una pregunta es que estoy tratando de sacar los valores de una matriz pero al momento de referirlo aparece que es "undefined", tengo el siguiente codigo con el traigo la matriz desde una consulta de php:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#buscadorMarca").change(function(){
            var select = $('#buscadorMarca').val();
            
            $.ajax({
                url:'../Backend/BuscarLineaVehiculo.php',
                type:'POST',
                data: {select:select},
                success: function (data){ 
                    console.log(data)
                    console.log(data[0].id)

                },
             });
        });
    });
```

Cuando hago el console.log(data) da como resultado la siguiente matriz: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí], pero al momento de referirme al valor de la clave 0 aparece "undefined":[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues deberia funcionar bien, fíjate en este ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/9nz4t5vs/  (abre la consola donde pone console(beta) para ver la consola). Si acaso prueba de convertirlo primero a objeto con `data = JSON.parse(data)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo más probable es que estés recibiendo esa respuesta como cadena y no como objeto JSON:

```js
let str = '[{"id":"biz 100", "text":"biz 100"}]';
// La salida es igual a la que muestras, pero es una cadena
console.log(str);
// Si tratas de acceder al primer elemento, solo aparecerá el corchete
console.log(str[0]);

// Solo hay que interpretarla
let data = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(data);
console.log(data[0].id);
```

La opción más sencilla sería indicarle a jQuery que esperas recibir un objeto JSON agregando la propiedad `dataType`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#buscadorMarca").change(function(){
        var select = $('#buscadorMarca').val();
        
        $.ajax({
            url:'../Backend/BuscarLineaVehiculo.php',
            type:'POST',
            data: {select:select},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data){ 
                console.log(data)
                console.log(data[0].id)

            },
         });
    });
});
```

En caso de dudas, consulta la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Muchas gracias, ese era el problema

Comment: @ÁngelZuluaga Por favor, acepta la respuesta si te ha sido de utilidad para que la pregunta no quede pendiente de respuesta eternamente. Mira este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) para aprender a aceptar respuestas, gracias.  De paso haz el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y para ver porque es importante aceptar las respuestas válidas a tus preguntas.

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que lo recibes com JSON y no como objeto, por lo tanto debes parsearlo para tratarlo como objeto de este modo:

```
console.log(data)
data = JSON.parse(data)
console.log(data[0].id)
```

usando el método [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: ¡Fuiste más rápido! xD

Comment: Es que te enrollas mucho :-D  Pero vamos, tu respuesta es mucho más completa... yo he tirado por lo práctico esta vez (confio en que aceptará la tuya, es mucho mejor)